# HTML "Select" Doesn't POST to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, post

Im attempting to add a basic select function onto a signup form to post the selected data onto a PHP script.

My issue is, when calling the $_POST['nameofselect'], php suggests that It cannot find the select.

The snippet from my signup page is as follows

```
<form class="form-signup" id="usersignup" name="usersignup" method="post" action="createuser.php">
        <h2 class="form-signup-heading">Register</h2>
        <input name="newuser" id="newuser" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" autofocus>
        <input name="email" id="email" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">

  <p>Favorite Car!: </p>
   <select name="cars">
   <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
   <option value="saab">Saab</option>
     <option value="opel">Opel</option>
   <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>

        <input name="password1" id="password1" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
        <input name="password2" id="password2" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Repeat Password">

        <button name="Submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign up</button>
        <div id="message"></div>
      </form>
```

The PHP named createuser.php is as follows, its simple, just posts the outcome of what is being posted.

```
<?php

echo $_POST['cars'];
?>
```

For some reason when posted i get the response of

```
Notice: Undefined index: cars in /fakepath/createuser.php on line 3.
```

Any advice for this?

Answer (score -1):

That's just typo.

In your `PHP` code you are looking for `cars` index but in your `HTML` code you are using `car`.

Comment: That was actually a mistake when i changed the variable names for the purpose of this thread, i fixed the question and my code, still not functioning.

Comment: @ChristopherAllen so try checking `$_POST` content with `var_dump`.

Comment: Upon doing a var dump, cars did not appear but everything else did as normal. How could this be? Select is clearly defined as name in the code